# If there are interface modules of encoder,camera,top and motor in ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If there are interface modules of encoder,camera,top and motor in ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56560/if-there-are-interface-modules-of-encoder,camera,top-and-motor-in-ros?/) by [yangtao09](https://answers.ros.org/users/4315/yangtao09/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-02-27**:
Please formulate all your questions better and provide more information..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need a something to do I/O like an arduino and a signal amplifier which amplifies this signal to a voltage and current usable for the motor.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0